# streambuilder inside forloop inside another streambuilder

Tags: flutter

I need some help with Streambuilder. I have a streambuilder inside a streambuilder.
I'm using for loop to get docid from first stream. and then using it in the 2nd stream. But the issue is the 2nd stream is only taking the first docid.

```
StreamBuilder<List<AuctionPostsModel>>(
                  stream: DatabaseService().auctionPosts,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                      for (AuctionPostsModel post in snapshot.data ?? []) {
                        return StreamBuilder<List<AuctionBids>>(
                          stream: DatabaseService().auctionBids(post.docid),
                          builder: (context, snapshott) {
                            print(post.docid);
                            try {
                              if (snapshott.hasData &&
                                  snapshott.connectionState ==
                                      ConnectionState.active) {
                                for (AuctionBids bidData
                                    in snapshott.data ?? [])
                                  return bidData.auctionNotification == false
                                      ? Container()
                                      : Stack(
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                              child: Container(
                                                  height: post.uid != _userId
                                                      ? 0
                                                      : null,
                                                  child: Container(
```

the print shows this

```
(2)I/flutter ( 3762): Cznv9cC3JpVadiiVVpIS
```

However if i print it above the 2nd stream, it prints correctly

```
I/flutter ( 3762): Cznv9cC3JpVadiiVVpIS
I/flutter ( 3762): ZRh3oB7sW27MjMOwnt9E
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Stream 1 is outer stream which contains a `for loop`. This for loop returns a widget inside the stream that is, it runs only **once**. So, you get only first widget out. You mentioned Stream 2, I can't see where it is and what it does. If you want to list out the widgets, it's better to use `ListView` instead of `loop`. Because when you return something in a loop every time, it runs only once.

Comment: here is first stream ```stream: DatabaseService().auctionPosts,``` and here is 2nd stream ```stream: DatabaseService().auctionBids(post.docid),```
Also i must use for loop, because in ListView i can't stack items and i have to stack them.

Comment: Okay, I get what you meant. I think you are using for loop in the wrong place. If you want to Stack them, you need to use for loop inside `children` of the `Stack` and not loop of Stacks. Your main problem I see is with the loop. Can you please explain in more detail on why you are using the loop? (both for loops)

Comment: If i use loop way below in the stack, then i can't get the post.docid from the snapshot and hence can't provide the docid that is required for the 2nd stream.
I'm using the loop and not Listview because i want to stack the items above each other which is not possible with ListView

Comment: The implementation is wrong when you use it outside the stack. It causes you to have only `Stack -> Container` every time. You won't be having 2 Containers stacked up because when return is inside the loop, it doesn't behave as a loop. I would suggest `Stack -> loop -> stream 1 -> stream 2 -> container` this approach. Once try this out. In this case, loop will be having many widgets which stacks up inside the stack.

Comment: ```Stack -> loop -> stream 1 -> stream 2 -> container```
the loop needs data from stream 1 to loop inside... It's not possible to loop without it.
Anyway, i changed the code structure. Instead of having 2 streams i'm now having 1 single stream.

Comment: Great, it makes things simple when there is one stream. So, probably you can use `Stream -> Stack -> loop -> container` which makes the things inside loop stack up.

Comment: Yeah, i tried it and it worked. But had to store the data of the 2 streams in one another database. Which i feel isn't the perfect solution..

Comment: I might have some idea if you really want to use two streams. Why not have it like `Stream 1 -> Stack -> loop 1 -> Stream 2-> Stack -> loop 2 -> container`? Here, we can use two stacks(nested) instead of one. I feel this might be better instead of storing something again back. Trying this out can probably give better functionality.

Comment: The issue isn't with stack. It's with the Stream and loop -> Stream and loop. The issue is as you said before "Stream 1 is outer stream which contains a for loop. This for loop returns a widget inside the stream that is, it runs only once. So, you get only first widget out. " And your way doesn't solve it ?

Comment: The recent one which I sent before, I used two stacks which has loops inside it. Loops inside stack will work fine because you can have multiple children inside stack but not in other widgetts. So, 2 stacks -> 2 loops. It is just a theory which might possibly work. We were using only one stack before, maybe using 2 stacks (nested) can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by using one Stream instead of two. I had to store the data in one another single document in firestore. This way instead of getting the docid from one stream and using loop to get the index and then using the docid from first loop into the second stream i just had stored the data and docid in one single stream, Accessed that stream and compared if the docid matches the docid inside the newly created doc and it worked.